# I cannot get footer to stay centered

Tags: html, footer

I have searched quiet a bit and found a lot of css that I tested but margin: 0 auto; has not worked and. I cannot get my footer to stay center and also at the bottom. I can get it to the bottom and I can get it centered but not both.

Here is the HTML

```
<div align="center">    
    <table class="copyrightbar">    
        <tr>
            <td class="noborder">
                <img  class="ledge" src="images\lefthalfcircle.png">
            </td>
            <td class="noborder" >
            <img class="copyrightimg" src="images\copyright.png">
            </td>
            <td class="noborder">
                <img class="redge" src="images\righthalfcircle.png">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.copyrightbar
{
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   float: left;
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 10px;
   display:block;
}
```

I am not sure why it won't stay centered or what I am doing wrong. Right now the thin is set up to stay at the bottom only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rPBU/)

I know the images aren't actually showing, but it should display as you required.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">    
    <table class="copyrightbar">    
        <tr>
            <td class="noborder">
                <img  class="ledge" src="images\lefthalfcircle.png">
            </td>
            <td class="noborder" >
                <img class="copyrightimg" src="images\copyright.png">
            </td>
            <td class="noborder">
                <img class="redge" src="images\righthalfcircle.png">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}    

.copyrightbar {
   margin: 0 auto;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

​

Comment: Thanks! I am just curious what made it work, was it setting the width of the wrapper to 100%? Aside from removing all the location css in the .copyrightbar.

Comment: Hi, it is indeed the width: 100%. Without that, the wrapper has the same width as the inner table, and thus there is no margin for it to be positioned within the wrapper. But when the wrapper is 100% wide, the table can be freely positioned, and margin: 0 auto; will center it in the wrapper

Comment: P.S. I'd encourage you to play around with the jsfiddle to learn how the display, margin/padding and position tags work together. It's VERY useful to know. A tip is to apply a background-color to each element to see the space it's taking up and where it's positioned.

Answer (score 1):

What is the point to using float:left ?  If you want it centered, floating this entire element to the left serves no purpose since it does the exact opposite of what you want.

However, if you want to keep it, then your wrapper div should be given an id, lets say id="footer" then use this css

```
#footer {
    width:400px (not sure if that is too wide or not, you can play around with it until it is the right width)
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class or ID to the wrapper div. Then use CSS to place it at the bottom using `position: fixed'.

Then set a width on your table (via CSS) and use the `margin: 0 auto` declaration you mention above. (Oh and remove `position: fixed` from the table)

Comment: I added --->.wrapper
{
   position: fixed;
   margin: 0 auto;
}<--- but it did not help any. So I added--->.wrapper
{
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 10px;
   float: left;
   margin: 0 auto;
} <--- instead and it at least is at the bottom but still not centered.

Answer (score 0):

May be because your CSS file has { float: left; }?